# dotnetcore CopyToOutputDirectory creates deep nested folder structure

Tags: .net-core, csproj

Having below config

```
<Content Include="**/*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

creates a deeply nested structure e.g. 
bin > debug > netstandard2.0 > [folder with json files] then again bin > debug > netstandard2.0 > [folder with json files] bin > ...

even though project only has flat structure
root

> [folder]
>    *json files

so expected to have only 
bin > debug > netstandard2.0 > folder

this is on macos using jetbrains rider, also happens when building with
dotnet build

thanks.

Comment: It appears to do so on subsequent builds e.g. first build creates a correct one level copy, on the next build it adds another level within output dir bin > debug > netstandard2.0 > bin > debug > netstandard.. and continues doing so recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether its web or non-web project (used SDK), you should update existing items that take already have the necessary exclusions set up:

```
<None Update="**/*.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
<!-- Web SDK sets some JSON files to Content -->
<Content Update="**/*.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
```

alternatively, if you want to add some files to content items, use excludes like this:

```
<Content Include="**\*.txt"
         CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"
         Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder);$(DefaultWebContentItemExcludes)" />
<!-- ensure that project systems aren't confused when the same file is listed in different items -->
<None Remove="**\*.txt" />
```